# Android align checkboxes on same vertical line

Tags: android, checkbox, vertical-alignment

I want to align a group of check boxes in Android at the center of screen and on the same vertical line similar to group of radio buttons. I searched on Internet but didn't see any solution.

For example, I have a questionnaire "why do you visit this shop" and have four answers 1. Location 2. Service 3. Facility 4. All of above. Users can choose more than one answer.

If I use radio button, I just group these inside a radio group. I don't know how to do with check box. Or I need to use an other form widget.

Edited

Similar to this image
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9xpIwq2ZRYfQUtYM3RmYVU5VTA/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put them all in a `LinearLayout` and give each of them the same `android:layout_marginRight`:

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/foo"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip">
        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:text="this is a checkbox"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:checked="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @peterpeiguo.

I added an image of the concept. Please kindly see again.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way around. Thanks for you idea.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
<LinearLayout   
            android:id="@+id/foo1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/bar1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="this is a checkbox"
                android:checked="false" />
        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/bar2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hello"
                android:checked="false" />        
</LinearLayout>
```